# Is there a way to have Bash autocomplete nested subdirectories in a single tab, when they function as a single directory?

Tags: linux, bash

Frequently in software development I come across nested subdirectories such as `src/main/java/com/mycompany` or `src/package_name/language` where each of these subdirectories only contains a single directory and no other files or directories. I know GitHub automatically treats these as a single path, but I was wondering if it was possible to have Bash save me the extra tab presses by tab completing `src/main/java/com/mycompany` all at once if the directory structure is unambiguous, rather than `src` TAB `main` TAB `java`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It's probably possible; for example, the tab completion for `cd` is often (if you have Bash-completion installed) a function like [this](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/5927d5733be672268ae15e78fd3b1a5d91cfbc2d/bash_completion#L2221-L2274); you could probably hook into this and check for each directory if there's only one child directory, and then return the full path as a completion candidate. I imagine this behaviour might also be annoying at time, like when you *do* want to `cd` into a non-leaf directory to add something.